# How can I add auto generated labels for topic titles in PDF output using DITA-OT?

Tags: pdf-generation, dita, dita-ot

I'm generating a PDF using DITA-OT. I'd like to add labels to topic titles such as "Exercise 1:". I know that we can do this by adding variables to the `en.xml` file for **section titles, chapter titles**, etc. How can we extend this functionality to topic titles?

More specifically, I want to add "**Exercise: #**" and "**Task: #**" to Heading level 1 and Heading level 2 topic titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the XSLT stylesheet "dita-ot/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/xsl/fo/topic.xsl" there is a template which matches the topic title:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="processTopicTitle">
```

Maybe you can create a PDF customization plugin which overwrites this XSLT template and adds your own changes to it.

Comment: Thank you Radu Coravu!